# Is there any way to package a reactjs project into a react native module and render it directly in the react native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have many web projects developed using reactjs, but our new project uses react native. I couldn't re-implement everything in React Native at once, but using webveiw would load too slowly. I want to find a way to package the web project into a React Native module and use it directly

I hope there is a solution to implement my idea, or at least optimize the loading speed of webview to a great extent

Comment: you need react native !